# Calling a controller and its view from _Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creatig an MVC project from scratch and I can't call a controller and its view from _Layout.

- I created View XMenu in folder Views/XMenu/
- It has its own controller XMenuController in folder Controllers/

[image]

In _Layout, I call controller using Html.RenderAction. I also tried Html.Action but with no success.

```
<div>
      @{ @Html.RenderAction("MenuAction", "XMenu") };           
</div>
```

Controller XMenu

```
 public class XMenuController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /XMenu/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult MenuAction()
        {        
        return PartialView();

        }

    }
```

View XMenu:

```
My Menu
```

I haven't put any parameters yet, just trying to call a controller and its view from _Layout, but get error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)'
>   has some invalid arguments

- Is it possible to call a controller and its view from _Layout?
- How should I call it?

**EDIT:**

I tried @Html.Action("MenuAction", "XMenu") };

[image]

I tried renaming view to MenuAction.cshtml.

[image]

I tried  @{ Html.RenderAction("MenuAction", "XMenu"); };
[image]

I renamed my Controller and my View.

[image]

Comment: Why are you not trying @Html.Partial()? It loads view with appropriate action.

Comment: Yes, I tried @Html.Partial(), but it loads only partial view, without its controller. And later I will need its controller's methods for passing parameters.

Comment: maby `@{ Html.RenderAction("MenuAction", "XMenu") };`? I mean `@` char problem?

Comment: Rename your partial view as MenuAction.cshtml and try. Or @Html.Action("MenuAction", "XMenu") };

Comment: Have you tried `@{ Html.RenderAction("MenuAction", "XMenu") }`, without the second `@` and semicolon?

Comment: See my last edit. I got errors. I don't know what I'm doing wrong... Is it possible to call a controller and its view from _Layout?

Comment: try `return PartialView("XMenu");` Or, the more preferred way would be to rename your partial view to match the child action's name.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile it. And belive your problem is with your method signature. It should be:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("MenuAction", "XMenu"); };
```

Comment: @Delmonte you do something wrong, i create new project and all works fine after my change